# Need help on Vb code i have created

Tags: vb.net, cmd, ping

i am working on this project, which I login in to router . ping to some IP, if i increase the packet size to 4, the O/p will be display result of Percent & roundtrip quicker as compared to packet count-100 which takes time. so need code so that Vb check the file real-time like "screening window" and if wherever it find the Percent & roundtrip on cmd windows it will send logout/exit/some my stuff to cmd and display in the MsgBox .

i need help on Vb checking the txt file real-time , if not found, close the file and again open for rechecking and so on or may be like "screening window" ..

pl help .

My original Code is below.

```
====================

Private Sub Runcode()
i = Shell("\windows\system32\cmd.exe", vbNormalFocus)

Dim MY_SERVER_IP As String
Dim LocalHost As String
Dim SourceIP As String
Dim DestinationIP As String
Dim Number As String
Dim Size As String
MY_SERVER_IP = "97.1.2.2"


Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))


SendKeys "telnet " & MY_SERVER_IP & " 6000 -f D:\Report\PING.txt{ENTER}"
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
SendKeys " Command to Login the Router"
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
SendKeys " PING IP: SRN=0, SN=14, SIPADDR=some_Source_IP , DESTIP=Some_Destination_IP, CONTPING=NO, TIMES=4, PKTSIZE=1400; "

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:50"))
' for short packet Number also i have to wait around 50 sec
' here currently Times=4 means it will recieve 4 reply packets which will show the result in 4 sec
' but same if i change it to 50 it wll take around 30-50 sec
Dim sFileName As String
Dim iFileNum As Integer
Dim sBuf As String
Dim Fields As String
Dim buffer As String
buffer = "round-trip"
sFileName = "D:\Report\PING.txt"
''//Does the file exist?
If Len(Dir$(sFileName)) = 0 Then
MsgBox ("File not Created")
End If
iFileNum = FreeFile()
Open sFileName For Input As iFileNum
Do While Not EOF(iFileNum)
Line Input #iFileNum, Fields
If Fields <> buffer Then
Call hint
Else
MsgBox ("didnt Work")
End If

Loop
Close iFileNum
End Sub
Close sFileName


Sub hint()

Dim myFile As String, text As String, textline As String, pkt As String, rndtrip As String

Dim objShell
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.AppActivate "Telnet " & MY_SERVER_IP
objShell.SendKeys "Logout{enter}"
objShell.Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
objShell.SendKeys "Exit{enter}"

myFile = "D:\Report\PING.txt"
Open myFile For Input As #1
Do Until EOF(1)
Line Input #1, textline
text = text & textline
Loop
Close #1


pkt = Trim(Mid(text, InStr(text, "Percent") + 0, (InStrRev(text, "packet") + 0) - (InStr(text, "Percent") + 1)))
rndtrip = Trim(Mid(text, InStr(text, "round-trip") + 0, (InStrRev(text, "ms") + 0) - (InStr(text, "round-trip") + 1)))

Call MsgBox("Percent : " & pkt & " Round-Trip : " & rndtrip & ".", vbOKOnly)

End Sub
```

Comment: See [Ask].  Particularly the part about writing a good title `Write a title that summarizes the specific problem`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Adding this line. Your loop will only fire if the file exist.

```
 If System.IO.File.Exists(myFile )

 Do Until EOF(1)
 Line Input #1, textline
 text = text & textline
 Loop
 Close #1
 else 

 ' if the file is not there rerun the method. 
 Runcode()

 end if
```